# Creating multiple sockets using single client in chat application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, port

I am testing a chat application for number of users. So what I am trying is  as follows:

I am trying to run my chat application by  login for chat for only one user for 1000 times in for loop. here is my part of code .

```
public void LoginChatConnect() {
    try {

        // while(true){
         for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        System.out.println("inside loginChatLogin");
        String userId = "Rahul";
        String password = "rahul";
        sockChatListen = new Socket("localhost", 5004);
        // /sockChatListen.
        dosChatListen = new DataOutputStream(
                sockChatListen.getOutputStream());
        disChatListen = new DataInputStream(sockChatListen.getInputStream());
        dosChatListen.writeUTF(userId);
        dosChatListen.writeUTF(password);
        // System.out.println(dosChatListen.toString());
        dosChatListen.flush();


        // sockChatListen.close();
        boolean b = sockChatListen.isClosed();

        System.out.println("connection open**********************" + b);
        sockChatListen.close();

        System.out.println("connection closed**********************" + b);
        count++;
        System.out.println("count" + count);
         }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In above code I am just trying to login for only one user for 1000 times. But after certain login it is giving me this socket error.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
```

Here I am trying to create a connection with a single port 5004. why I am getting error after 100+ successful connections(login).?

How should I recover this problem?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your post is that you want to simulate 1000 users logging to the chat server concurrently. I believe you are trying to test the load on your chat server.

However, from your code, I see that you are establishing and closing the socket connection every time in the loop. This is similar to 1000 users waiting in a queue and attempting to login to the server one after the other. This does not simulate the concurrent load but a 1000 sequential calls to the server and would not be appropriate to load test your server.

My comments are based on the above stated understanding. Please calrify if this is not the case.

Regarding the exception you get, I have no idea why it should not work after 100+ attempts. May be you need to check your server side code to figure out the problem.

Comment: ok. So is it possible to create 1000 sequential connections by single socket client ?

Comment: Yes. Every time to inistantiate your client, it will create a new client socket that is connected to your server. So you can have 1000 instances (or any feasible number) of your client application simultaneously to simulate concurrent connections. However, it just not enough to establish and close the connection immediately. You can maintain the connection for some time and exchange some arbitary data with the server to simulate the concurrent users.